# Firestore adds search conditions and cannot continue to monitor

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-firestore

When the search condition is not added, the changes can be listened to in real time, but after I add the search condition, I cannot continue to monitor the changes. Why?

original code

```
 db.collection("Users").document("pZOLUl9tyVdOKzyeUScIZ8BysPm1")
.collection("RechargeCoin")
.order(by: "date", descending: true)
.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

Code after adding search criteria

```
  db.collection("Users").document("pZOLUl9tyVdOKzyeUScIZ8BysPm1")
.collection("RechargeCoin")
.whereField("review2", isEqualTo: "未確認")
.order(by: "date", descending: true)
.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
```

Modified code cannot listen for changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every query on Firestore needs an index that matches the exact fields that you order/filter on. When no such index exists, the query can't be executed and the SDK throws an error.

The behavior you're describing typically means that the necessary index is missing. You'll want to catch and log any errors coming from the Firestore API calls and then check in the error message for a URL. This URL takes you directly to the Firestore console in a page where you can create the necessary index with a single click (all fields will be prepopulated in the URL already).